# Slidesjs not working in codeigniter uri path

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, slideshow

I am using Slidesjs it working fine in below url

http://www.mysoko.in/demo/Simple/

And same code not working in below codeigniter

http://www.mysoko.in/demo/index.php/home/slides

Pls help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the full URL for all images, e.g.:

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/charity-graphic-design-2.gif
```

... assuming your images are stored in a folder like so: "example.com/img".